# Please tell me what's wrong in my sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

i am creating an application in codeigniter. I am creating a function of searching tutorial from database. But i am getting error. Please check my code.

```
    function get_tuts($query, $limit, $offset) {

    $offset = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE  MATCH ( title, desc ) AGAINST (?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"; 
    $q = $this->db->query($sql, array($query, $limit, $offset));

    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach($row->result() as $row){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }
            return $data;
}
```

but i am getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc ) AGAINST ('yahoo') LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' at line 1
```

Comment: Is there a stray ' in your input? Sanitize your database input's or risk the wrath of little bobby tables.

Comment: @Matten i am using MySQL

Comment: @asawyer: CodeIgniter automatically escapes the query when doing it this way.  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved word. Add ` to desc:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE  MATCH ( title, `desc` ) AGAINST (?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
```

Answer (score 3):

The word `desc` is a reserved word in mysql. Try surrounding the column name with backticks `.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're receiving says that `desc` is a reserved keyword in MySql.

```
use near 'desc ) AGAINST ('yahoo') LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' at line 1
```